# wordpress website not getting indexed by search engine

Tags: wordpress

I recently developed a wordpress website and hosted it successfully a week back. But the problem is it is not getting indexed by any search engine. My previous website got indexed within 3 days of launch. I tried using "wordpress yoast SEO" plugin, even tried it with "Google webmaster tool". Please help.

website link: http://www.teamstudsat.in

Answer (score 0):

You should update the page links so they contain the page names instead of the page id's.  In the dashboard, go to Settings > Permalinks and select "Post Name" as the permalink structure.

The SEO Yoast Plugin also gives you detailed advice for improving the SEO of each page.  Click on the "Page Analysis" tab of the SEO Yoast plugin box.

Giving meaningful alt tags to all the images on your site also helps.